# Why is it a borel set on the boundary of the unit ball of $E^n$?

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Given $C$ convex body (compact convex set with non-empty interior points) in $E^n$ symmetric about the origin and containing the unit ball.

Let $A(r)$ denote ,for every real $r >1$, the subset of the boundary of the unit ball of $E^n$
obtaind by projecting on the boundary of the unit ball of $E^n$ from the origin ,the boundary points of $C$ which belong to $rBn$ (ball in $E^n$ of radius $r$ ).

**I want to prove that $A(r)$ is a borel set on the boundary of the unit ball of $E^n$**

Answer (score 0):

Because the set is equal to $\frac{1}{r} \cdot(C\cap (r\cdot B_n ))$ and hence it is compact.

Comment: i think that this set can't be written in this form 
since i want projection of the **boundary points of C** which belong to **r$B_n$** i.e. that their norms are <=r
so why you divide (C intersect r*$B_n$) by r